# Devise: Submitting Devise forms seem to be using the GET method as opposed to POST, not logging in/signing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have just set up Devise for my User model. I tried to register using Devise, however the form is not submitting. When I press the "Register" button on my register page, the page refreshes and the submitted parameters appear in the URL of the page, as if Devise is submitting the form using GET as opposed to POST.

For example, this is what appears in the address bar of my browser after I press the 'Register' button.

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/login?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=YMjcWnx3RCpdZbkmfcky%2F0ob47fPTCM1pTrg%2Bq3k%2FWA%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=test@test.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=test&commit=Login
```

Here is the code for my Devise registration view (registrations/new.html.erb):

```
<div class="devise-form">
<div class="well">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Register</legend>
      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control input-lg', placeholder: 'Email' %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <%= f.password_field :password, required: true, class: 'form-control input-lg', placeholder: 'Password' %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, required: true, class: 'form-control input-lg', placeholder: 'Password confirmation' %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <%= f.submit 'Register', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had accidentally forgotten to remove the actual HTML  tags that were surrounding the Rails form_for method.